# What's the difference between Extend and Require property in sencha touch 2.0?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Basically here's what i have gone through so far:

**Extend:**

Read [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-extend)

> Basically extends means *subclassing*,in which all the properties of
>   the parent class can be inherited down into the child class.

**Require:**

Read [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-require)

```
Loads all classes by the given names and all their direct dependencies.
```

*Am I wrong to think these are **similar**?*

I couldn't find any other differences, can someone explain the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Extends** 
Subclassing means if your creating a class B that Extend the class A, B can be treated like an A, and inherit method and attributes.
A's methods and attributes become part of your new class B.

**Requires**
It's just a loading mecanism that assure that some required class are loaded before you can use it. For exemple, if you need to display a message box, you will call :

```
Ext.Msg.confirm("Confirmation", "Do you want to add " + value  + " to the database ?");
```

*Ext.Msg* is not a part of your class, you're basically just telling the system to display a Popup. But if you do that when your app launch, before the class *Ext.Msg* has been loaded, well it will fail.

To summary :

**Extends** => when you need to become a class X

**Requires** => when you need to use a class X

Answer (score 0):

**Extends** -- The class will extend to one parent class. u can see this in controller or store or model which extends to one parent class

Eg

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.ExtendParent", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
```

**Requires** -- The class which needs the functionality from one or more other classes.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.ExtendParent", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'MyApp.store.ParentStore',
        'MyApp.view.ParentView'
    ],
```

Comment: So the difference is requires gives functionality from multiple classes and extend gives only 1?

Comment: Partially yes. Extends will try to inherit the behaviour of super class. but requires try to call for specific usage. Dont try to dig deeper. in this eg "Ext.MessageBox" for showing dialog u should call inside the requires thats it

Comment: I wouldn't say partially. `extends` means the class will become a subclass. `requires` just indicates that the requested classes should be loaded before the class is finished being defined.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Good explanation. I will wait for 1 more day before accepting Nitro's ans.